# Is there a setting to set staff_url for the django-helpdesk emails being sent?

Tags: django

Is there a setting to set staff_url for the django-helpdesk emails being sent?  The href for "View Online" points to example.com instead of my site.  (The subsequent path is correct).
In admin/ I only have one site and it is correct.  I don't see example.com anywhere in my code.

Comment: According to the docs, it seems like it is supposed to be coming from Sites.  There don't seem to be any settings specific for this.  Yet, it doesn't work.  Looking at ticket.staff_url and how it is loaded, it all points to Sites in Django.  Yet I don't have an example.com site.  It's like it isn't overriding the default.

Comment: What do you get if you import the `Site` model and print  `Site.objects.get_current()` in your code?